how can I get SUPERUSER permission on rooted Android 11 and 12
I've got Memu emulator (Android 12) rooted.
How do you display an alert dialog like this in Kotlin?

I added codes below but didnt' work.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />

and
fun requestRootAccess(context: Context): Boolean {
    return try {
        // Try to get root access
        val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", "id"))
        val os = DataOutputStream(process.outputStream)

        // Run a simple root command to test
        os.writeBytes("id\n")
        os.flush()

        // Wait for the process to finish and get the result code
        val resultCode = process.waitFor()
        os.close()

        if (resultCode == 0) {
            // Root access granted, show success message
            Toast.makeText(context, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            true
        } else {
            // Root access denied, show failure message
            Toast.makeText(context, "denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(context, "interrupted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    }
}


fun requestRootAccess(context: Context): Boolean {
return try {
    // Try to get root access
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", "id"))
    val os = DataOutputStream(process.outputStream)

    // Run a simple root command to test
    os.writeBytes("id\n")
    os.flush()

    // Wait for the process to finish and get the result code
    val resultCode = process.waitFor()
    os.close()

    if (resultCode == 0) {
        // Root access granted, show success message
        Toast.makeText(context, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        true
    } else {
        // Root access denied, show failure message
        Toast.makeText(context, "denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    false
} catch (e: InterruptedException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Toast.makeText(context, "interrupted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    false
}

}

Please no "code only" answer,

Please no "code only" answer
